# Relate data between two 2d arrays based on a shared value in a protected property

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays `$userArray` and `$differentArray`.  
**question:** I am trying to find the index value from `$userArray` where `$userId` matches from `$differentArray` so that i can pull the first/last names

`print_r` of $userArray outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [userId] => ID Object
        (
            [_unknown:protected] => 
            [id_:protected] => 8k6Y4FTrnxKY45XrVkXvVJhL
        )
        [firstName] => Joe
        [lastName] => Smith
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [userId] => ID Object
        (
            [_unknown:protected] => 
            [id_:protected] => pCvR9qvIgGv8WyejcKmRtGD8
        )
        [firstName] => Sue
        [lastName] => Miller
    )
)
```

`print_r` of $differentArray outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 1363800434868
        [userId] => ID Object
        (
            [_unknown:protected] => 
            [id_:protected] => 8k6Y4FTrnxKY45XrVkXvVJhL
        )

        [someTxt] => aaaa
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 1363800858828
        [userId] => ID Object
        (
            [_unknown:protected] => 
            [id_:protected] => 8k6Y4FTrnxKY45XrVkXvVJhL
        )
        [someTxt] => cccc
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 1363817564430
        [userId] => ID Object
        (
            [_unknown:protected] => 
            [id_:protected] => pCvR9qvIgGv8WyejcKmRtGD8
        )
        [someTxt] => ccc
    )
)
```

**and here is my attempt, but it only outputs Joe Smith
*** `$differentArray` is constructed the same way as `$userArray`

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($differentArray)){
    $userId = $differentArray[$i]['userId'];
    $key = array_search( $userId, $userArray );
    $firstName = $userArray[$key]['firstName'];
    $lastName = $userArray[$key]['lastName'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: actually your while loop should never stop...

Comment: @ITroubs is right. You need to `$i++` at the end. What is `$total` set to?

Comment: fixed the question,  the loop was just a demo, not intended for literal interpretation.  sorry for the confusion

Comment: So `$differentArray` is an array of ID Objects like `$userArray`?

Comment: @Wiseguy sorry,  long day.  revised question.   ID Objects like `$userArray`

Comment: Does your ID class have a [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method that returns the `id` property when the object is treated as a string? If it did, your code might work (or close). If not, sounds like you might want to employ [`array_uintersect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php). (I have to run now and don't have time to do it, but hopefully that helps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, use `foreach`.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $total) {
    $userId = $differentArray[$i]['userId'];
    // $key = array_search($userId, $userArray);
    foreach ($userArray as $k => $user) {
        if($user["userId"] == $userId){
            $key = $k;
            break; // avoid useless loop
        }
    }
    $firstName = $userArray[$key]['firstName'];
    $lastName = $userArray[$key]['lastName'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the question marks here please `if($user["userId"]/*->???*/ == $userId){`

Comment: I don't know how `id_` is accessed since it's a protected attribute.

Comment: oh,  just like this `$differentArray[$i]['userId'];`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what that ID object is, but I assume it has a __toString method that returns the id property.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($differentArray as $user) {
    foreach ($userArray as $searchedUser) {
        if ($searchedUser['userId'] == $user['userId']) {
            $output[] = $searchedUser;
        }
    }
}
```

That will put the users you're looking for in $output array. This way you won't need the indices no more. You can just iterate over $output to pull out the values to variables. Eg.

```
foreach ($output as $user) {
    list($userId, $firstName, $lastName) = $user;
    // do your code here
}
```

If you're certain that there can only be one match in $userArray than you can break out from the loop when you find it or pull out the first one from the $output array.

I did a lot of guessing posting that answer since you didn't provide the $differentArray structure nor specified what it is you're actually expecting.

Comment: made adjustments to my question